# How to add show more button in angular-sidebar-menu

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sidebar

i am using angular-sidebar-menu(**v-1.5.0**) in my angular project

**What i want**
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bpf7.png)

I want to add a show more button in sidebar menu such that i can toggle the height of sidebar menu based on contents i want to show.

**What i have done**

I have tried to read the documentation and also issues in official gitHub repo but there doesn't seem to be any way to do it.

Link to github Repo
https://github.com/mledour/angular-sidebar-menu